# How can I change my age?

Tags: roblox

So When I logged into roblox I have put my age as ‘9’ and I am 14 years old. My username is poodles_246 and I would really like for roblox to try and change my age to 14 because it would really help out.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

For your question, if you want to change your age on roblox, you can refer to Roblox's help centre [here](https://en.help.roblox.com/hc/en-us/articles/360031323611-How-Do-I-Change-My-Age-)

However, in your case, you cannot change your age if your roblox age (age that you put in) is under 13, so you can either:

- wait for 4 years until your account turns 13 (unlikely)
- make a new roblox account and [trade](https://en.help.roblox.com/hc/en-us/articles/203313310-Trading-System) with your previous account to get your stuff
  onto your new account.

Hope this would help!

Comment: Please explain your downvote so that I can make adjustments

Comment: It's not your fault; it's just some people downvote answers to duplicate questions.